# How to solve line integrals - magnetic force on straight wire?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, integration, vector-fields, calculus

[image: Setup of the problem. A equilateral triangle]

Could any of you help me understand what I'm doing wrong, when solving this line integral? I believe I'm getting the wrong sign and the issue is probably the limits.

Consider an equilateral triangle with sides $a$, and a current $I_1$ running through it. The triangle is placed above a infinite wire with the current $I_2$.
Say I want to find the magnetic force on the wire going from $a$ to $b$, this is how I would do it:

The magnetic field is: $$\vec{B}_{2}=\frac{\mu_{0} I_{2}}{2 \pi x}\hat{y}$$.

I want to express $x$ in terms of $z$:
$$\tan \theta=\frac{x-d}{a-z} \Rightarrow x(z)=(a-z) \tan \theta+d$$ $$\frac{d x}{d z}=-\tan \theta \quad \Rightarrow d x=-\tan \theta d z$$ with $a/2<z<a$.

Now $d \vec{l}=d x \hat{x}+d y \hat{y}+d z \hat{z}$, so:
$$d \vec{l} \times \vec{B}_{2}(x)=(d x \hat{x}+d y \hat{y}+d z \hat{z}) \times \frac{\mu_{0} I_{2}}{2 \pi x(z)} \hat{y}=\frac{\mu_{0} I_{2}}{2 \pi x(z)}(d x \hat{z}-d z \hat{x})=-\frac{\mu_{0} I_{2}}{2 \pi x(z)}((\tan \theta \hat{z}+\hat{x}) d z)$$

So the magnetic force becomes:
$$\vec{F_{a \rightarrow b}}=I_{1} \int_{a\rightarrow b} d \vec{l} \times \vec{B}_{2}=-\frac{\mu_{0} I_{1} I_{2}}{2 \pi} \int_{a / 2}^{a} \frac{1}{(a-z) \tan \theta+d} d z(\tan \theta \hat{z}+\hat{x})$$ $$=-\frac{\mu_{0} I_{1} I_{2}}{2\sqrt{3} \pi} \ln \left(1+\frac{a \sqrt{3}}{2 d}\right)(\sqrt{3} \hat{z}+\hat{x})$$

Which clearly is in the wrong direction. What did I do wrong? (I'm pretty sure the magnitude is right, it's just the wrong direction)

---

Also how could I do this with some parameterization $t$? Let's say I define the vectors $\vec{a}=d \hat{x}+a \hat{z}, \quad \vec{b}=\left(d+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right) \hat{x}+\frac{a}{2} \hat{z}$. And the vector function representing the line from $a$ to $b$:

$$\vec{l}(t)=\vec{a}+(\vec{b}-\vec{a}) t$$

How could I then express $x(t)$ from the magnetic field in terms of my variable $t$. Because in this way, I could easily express $dl$ in terms of $dt$. And know I should integrate from $t=0$ to $t=1$. But I have no  idea how to relate the distance $x$ to $t$.

Answer (score 1):

This is my own interpretation of what went wrong. I wanted to integrate from the point a to b along the current $I_1$ (I'm assuming that's how you choose the boundaries, integrate along the current). So my limits should reflect this direction of integration. This should be done by starting at $a_z=a$ and end at $b_z=a/2$. So I should swap the boundaries.

---

To anser my second question, It's perfectly doable to integrate with the parameter t. Just note that $$\vec{l}(t)=x(t) \hat{x}+y(t) \hat{y}+z(t) \hat{z}=\vec{a}+(\vec{b}-\vec{a}) t$$.

So if you factorise $\vec{a}+(\vec{b}-\vec{a})t$ in terms of their cartesian basis, then it's fairly easy to read off $x(t)$

Comment: Yes seems correct to me